# Null check in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

I'm new to learning Python and was writing a function that returns the sum of a node's grandchildren (if they exist) within a binary tree and only managed to come up with this sloppy piece of code.

If anyone has any tips on improving the conciseness of my current function in a more pythonic way it would be much appreciated.

```
    def value_of_grandchildren(self, root):
        sum = 0
        if root.left and root.left.left:
            sum += root.left.left.val
        if root.left and root.left.right:
            sum += root.left.right.val
        if root.right and root.right.left:
            sum += root.right.left.val
        if root.right and root.right.right:
            sum += root.right.right.val
        return sum
```

Comment: make it a recursive function

Comment: Do you really *just* want the sum of grandchildren or do want the sum of all descendants and currently only have a depth down to grandchildren?

Comment: There are many examples on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line showing how to access a tree recursively, for a given quantity of levels, etc.  Please work one or more of those into your code before posting here -- as it says in the guidelines.  If you still have trouble, include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an inner function makes it slightly more readable.

```
def value_of_grandchildren(self, root):
    sum = 0
    def add(node):
        if not node:
            return
        if node.left:
            sum += node.left.val
        if node.right:
            sum += node.right.val
    add(root.left)
    add(root.right)
    return sum
```

**Update: Simpler?**

```
def value_of_grandchildren(self, root):
    def val(node):
        return node.val if node else 0
    def child(node):
        return val(node.left) + val(node.right) if node else 0
    return child(node.left) + child(node.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip checking two time for the existence of `root.left` and `root.right`

```
    def value_of_grandchildren(self, root):
        sum = 0
        if root.left:
            if root.left.left:
                sum += root.left.left.val
            if root.left.right:
                sum += root.left.right.val
        if root.right:
            if root.right.left:
                sum += root.right.left
            if root.right.right:
                sum += root.right.right.val
        return sum
```

For a more Pythonic way, you could generalize the function to sum all the n generation descendants of the root.

```
    def value_of_descendants(self, root, n):
        sums = 0
        if n == 0 and root:
            return root.val
        if root:
            sums += value_of_descendants(self, root.left, n-1)
            sums += value_of_descendants(self, root.right, n-1)
        return sums
```

Note that I didn't test this, but you should get the general idea.